# PDFTron: How to figure out if text is overflowing its bouding box

Tags: text, annotations, bounds, boundary, pdftron

I have made a PDF-document with multiline text fields. I'd like to know how I could check if the text is overflowing its bounds.

```php
TextWidget::GetVisibleContentBox()
```

and

```php
TextWidget::GetRect()
```

both seem to get the same `Rect`

Ok. Here's my slightly modified function for figuring out if a text field if overflowing. Took part of the logic from TCPDF:

```php
function isTextWidgetOverflowing (PDFTron\TextWidget $annot, float $leading = 9.6) {
    $text = $annot->GetText();

    /** @var PDFTron\Font */
    $font = $annot->GetFont();

    /** @var PDFTron\Rect */
    $rect = $annot->GetRect();

    $length = strlen($text);

    $rectW = $rect->Width();

    $lastSeparator = -1;
    $lines = 1;
    $sum = 0;

    for ($index = 0; $index < $length; $index++) {
        $character = $text[$index];
        $charCode = mb_ord($character);

        if (!($chW = $font->GetWidth($charCode))) {
            $chW = $font->GetMissingWidth();
        }

        $chW /= 1000.0;

        if (($charCode !== 160)
                && (($charCode === 173)
                || preg_match('/[^\S\xa0]/', $character)
                || (($charCode === 45)
                    && ($index > 0) && ($index < ($length - 1))
                    && @preg_match('/[\p{L}]/', $text[$index - 1])
                    && @preg_match('/[\p{L}]/', $text[$index + 1])
                )
            )
        ) {
            $lastSeparator = $index;
        }

        if ((($sum + $chW) > $rectW) || ($charCode === 10)) {
            ++$lines;

            if ($charCode === 10) {
                $lastSeparator = -1;
                $sum = 0;
            } else if ($lastSeparator !== -1) {
                $index = $lastSeparator;
                $lastSeparator = -1;
                $sum = 0;
            } else {
                $sum = $chW;
            }
        } else {
            $sum += $chW;
        }
    }

    if (mb_ord($text[$length - 1]) === 10) {
        --$lines;
    }

    return ($lines * $leading) > $rect->Height();
}
```

The `$chW` is most likely a bit wrong. Maybe I'd need to take into account the line spacing and font stretching. Where could these be found?

Also instead of hard-coding the `$leading` would be nice if I could somehow grab it of the PDF-document.

Comment: Currently there is no straightforward way to do this. Could you elaborate on why knowing if overflow has occurred, or not, is important for you? What do you do if it has, or has not,  overflowed?

Comment: I've made a form which I'm filling programmatically. I'd like to append a new document with the data of the overflowing text field if it's over its boundaries.

Comment: "append a new document" you mean a new page? If so, the PDF format does not really allow a form to cross two pages, and have different content. Though it is possible, but would require you to draw custom appearance on the second one. The simpler would be to add a new second form, but it would have a different unique form id name. Could you elaborate on your objective?

Comment: Can't this be done programmatically? I'd need to figure out either just if the content overflows it's given boundaries or I noticed PDFTrons Font -class having a method to figure out a single characters width. So maybe I could loop through all the characters in a text fields string and iterate some counter each time I either find a newline character or the text is overflowing the boundarys width. The only thing to figure out still then is how to get the calculated line height. I've set it to auto. Is it a n × font size or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution to determining if a Text Widget has overflowing text. The only thing I'd like to change is not relying on a parameter for the leading.

```php
function isTextWidgetOverflowing(PDFTron\TextWidget $annot, float $leading = 9.6) {
    $text = $annot->GetText();

    /** @var PDFTron\Font */
    $font = $annot->GetFont();

    $fontSize = $annot->GetFontSize();

    /** @var PDFTron\Rect */
    $rect = $annot->GetRect();

    $length = strlen($text);

    $rectW = $rect->Width();

    $lastSeparator = -1;
    $lines = 1;
    $sum = 0;

    for ($index = 0; $index < $length; $index++) {
        $char = $text[$index];
        $charCode = mb_ord($char);

        if (!($chW = $font->GetWidth($charCode))) {
            $chW = $font->GetMissingWidth();
        }

        $chW /= (1000.0 / $fontSize);

        if (($charCode !== 160)
            && (($charCode === 173)
                || preg_match('/[^\S\xa0]/', $char)
                || (($charCode === 45)
                    && ($index > 0) && ($index < ($length - 1))
                    && preg_match('/[\p{L}]/', $text[$index - 1])
                    && preg_match('/[\p{L}]/', $text[$index + 1])))
        ) {
            $lastSeparator = $index;
        }

        if ((($sum + $chW) > $rectW) || ($charCode === 10)) {
            ++$lines;

            if ($charCode === 10) {
                $lastSeparator = -1;
                $sum = 0;
            } else if ($lastSeparator !== -1) {
                $index = $lastSeparator;
                $lastSeparator = -1;
                $sum = 0;
            } else {
                $sum = $chW;
            }
        } else {
            $sum += $chW;
        }
    }

    if (mb_ord($text[$length - 1]) === 10) {
        --$lines;
    }

    return ($lines * $leading) > $rect->Height();
}
```